# What do you call a person who answers correspondence, mail, for a dog?

Tags: single-word-requests

Some children are going to be involved in responding to letters sent to a therapy dog.

Comment: The dog's "elves?" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas_elf

Comment: a *dogpal* ?...

Comment: Whatever, presumably they reply in doggerel.

Answer (score 3):

The word you're looking for could be "ghostwriter."

> ghostwrite: to write (something, such as a book) for someone else using that person's name (Merriam-Webster)

Assuming that they will be responding on the dog's behalf.

Answer (score 2):

PA (personal assistant), Admin, secretary, amanuensis, et.al.

Comment: How do these answers fit OP’s context of children answering letters to a therapy dog?

Comment: In the example above, it sounds like they are going to be "dogsbodies"

Comment: @Jim: very precisely. The children will be answering letters on behalf of another, which is one of the duties of a secretary. Whether the letters should be signed 'pp.' or '(dictated but not signed)' depends on the dog.

Comment: @TimLymington- But while a secretary *does* perform those functions, the children are not secretaries nor admins nor personal assistants. They are, perhaps, some form of volunteer *ghost writers* or something.